# VBA-Add Border around UsedRange minus Header rows (first 6 rows)

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am attempting to add border around a used range minus the header in this case rows 1-6.

In the code I have .select instead of .border the code is selecting the correct range object however giving me a run-time error 424 object required.

Any help on how to better reference this range would be great.

Code:

```
dim rng as range

dim rng2 as range 

set rng=worksheets("con-1").usedrange

set rng2=intersect(rng, rng.offset(6)).select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
 Dim rng As Range

 Set rng = Worksheets("con-1").UsedRange

 rng.Resize(rng.rows.count - 1).Offset(1).BorderAround 1
```

Comment: Sure a working answer, But I think it's better to clarify for OP the wrong with his code

Comment: @Waleed I think he can see what his code does, since it otains a selection of the respective range. What to be explained in such a situation? I cannot understad what he was waiting from that code line... And why.

Comment: A more correct way would be to first resize (shrink) and only then offset: `.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)`. Imagine the range has rows to the bottom, e.g. `A1:A1048576`. Then `.Offset(1)` would raise an error if you wouldn't resize it first. Of course, it is kind of nit-picking since you may argue about when will you ever have such a range.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, that's correct. For the OP used range of 6 rows I did not pay attention to this aspect. But, since theoretically the answer can be used by somebody else being in danger to meat that extreme mentioned case, it would be better to adapt the code as you suggest. I will swap the two properties. Thanks!

Comment: This Code above works yes, however I would like to know what I am doing wrong with reference to declaring my range objects. Object reference for VBA is something I wish to improve at any help would be great, again the above answer does work.

Comment: @NotACoderNoah Well, I thought it is obvious. So, `rng.Offset(6)` returns a range having the same number of rows and columns as the existing `UsedRange`, but 6 rows down. If you try  `rng.Offset(6)).Select` you will see what I tried explaining above. Then, intersecting such a range with the actual `UsedRange` will return **the common cells in both ranges**. If your `UsedRange` will have less than 6 rows, an intersection does not exist and it will not return anything. If more than 6, it will return a range starting from the 6th row bellow the first `UsedRange` row and its last one.

Comment: @NotACoderNoah Then `Select` does not make sense in the context you use it. You should firstly have `set rng2=intersect(rng, rng.offset(6))` followed by `rng2.Select`, or simple `intersect(rng, rng.offset(6)).Select`. Besides that, I would like to tell/remind that we here, when somebody answer our question, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for all your help and explanation, this intersection function is useful.